# CheckboxGroupInput with vertical Checkboxes

Tags: react-admin

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#checkboxgroupinput

For CheckboxGroupInput, `react-admin` places checkboxes horizontally as picture below:

[image]

My question is: Is it possible to have these checkboxes placed vertically?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been looking for the answer to this, and found it by delving into the groupbox code:

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
            source="tags"
            choices={tags}
            optionValue="id"
            optionText="title"
            row={false}
        />
```